# Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

In my application when I try to launch it Force Closed and the error pointing the line "setContentView(R.layout.Menu);" of the layout. And in the XML file it show the "OutOfMemoryError" image view in my layout. I am realy confused. Please guide me for further move.

**Edited:**

My application uses database, and at the very first time it parse some XML data and insert into the Sqlite database. My Outofmemory problem occurs only at the first time. Second time it works fine. I tried System.gc(). Is there any prob on that.

**This is my Log:**

```
E/dalvikvm-heap(2712): 105376-byte external allocation too large for this process.
VM won't let us allocate 105376 bytes

    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Test/com.Test.Menu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
    at com.Test.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:32)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
```

---

**This is my XML code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_Title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:onClick="onTitleClick" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Img_Title_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/title_bg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn_Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/title_al"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/pro"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onTitleClick" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_MainMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:onClick="onDoNothing">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:src="@drawable/main_bg" android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Img_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_al" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LI_Menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/RL_ExtraOption"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Img_logo"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Img_Buyer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_blink"
            android:onClick="Nextclick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:src="@drawable/buyer_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Img_Seller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_blink"
            android:onClick="Nextclick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/seller_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Img_Lender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_blink"
            android:onClick="Nextclick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/lender_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Img_myTitleRep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_blink"
            android:onClick="Nextclick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/my_title_rep_icon_al" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Img_Setup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_blink"
            android:onClick="Nextclick"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/setup_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RL_ExtraOption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/main_bottom_bg" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_RepName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/TR_ContactRep"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Btn_ContactRep"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/contact_rep_blink"
                android:onClick="ContactRep_Click" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Btn_MoreOption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/main_more_blink"
                android:onClick="onMoreClick" />
        </TableRow>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln_Mainmore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow04"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Btn_Rate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/property_blue_blink"
                    android:onClick="onRate"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Rate/Testimonial"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_SubFeature"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/property_blue_blink"
                    android:onClick="onSubFeature"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Submit A Feature"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow03"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Btn_ReferFrnd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/property_blue_blink"
                    android:onClick="onReferAFrnd"
                    android:text="Refer A Friend"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Btn_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/property_cancel_blink"
                    android:onClick="onClose"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a bitmap loaded as the background or source of an imageview.  What size is the bitmap?

Comment: Take a look at the right column here, under "Related" - there are a lot of other questions with the same or similar topic.

Comment: It's now 15.9 KB only. At first its nearly 240 KB and i tried reducing the size to 15.9 KB, but the prob exist.

Comment: Such exceptions are occured more often on old phones and not at the start. But in your case it seems that some ImageView control has reference to rather large image.

Comment: show your menu inflate code .

Comment: yes because some where there is problem in xml file of your code.this line in `Log Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>` Still occur in exception.

Comment: also check http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: i believe you are leaking activity context somewhere. though try following one of the approach i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: How big are the images @drawable/logo_al, @drawable/main_bg, and @drawable/title_bg ? Be sure to check all versions of the images.

Answer (score 6):

This is a typical problem when using Android's `ImageView` with large images on older devices (even if the file size is only several Kbs). The native graphics library called *skia* that is used to decode the image allocates native memory based on the image's dimensions, so the file size does not influence this directly.

Even if you omit the `src`-attribute in the XML layout definition to load the image yourself in your `onCreate()` method the same error will be triggered. The only way to get around this is to use an `inSampleSize` in `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` to perform downsampling directly during decoding (see [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966) for example). This itself raises the question of how to determine this scale factor.

The best solution I found when handling large images is replacing the `ImageView` with a `WebView` and load some minimal HTML like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/background.html");
```

where the content  of `raw/background.html` might be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="file:///android_res/drawable/background.png" />
</body>
```

The WebKit engine that is used in the WebView performs image loading in a much more efficient way, so that those memory allocation errors should be gone.

You can even use different images for portrait and landscape by putting them in `drawable-port` and `drawable-land`. But then you have to call `clearCache(false)` on the WebView instance in your `onDestroy()` method because otherwise the image cached on the first load will always be used (disabling caching on the WebView instance does not work).

Answer (score 6):

After spending a lot of time on this problem I found the solution!
All you need to do is ask for more memory.
Place this code inside your android manifest under:

```
<application>:
```

Put:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Worked great for me!
Please note that this solution works only on API 11 and above.

More info [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application)

Answer (score 4):

A lot of devices have very limited and restricted memory available to each device. A lot of older devices allocate 16MB of memory to your application, while some more modern devices might allocate 24MB or even 32MB (I've seen a device with only 14MB).

Whenever you load so many images into memory, this space fills up very quickly causing the OutOfMemoryError to be thrown. To overcome this problem, you should (as previous answers have said) shrink the images to thumbnails and only keep the thumbnails in device memory (reduced memory footprint) and have the images saved to SDCARD.

You can see how much memory your program is using from the DDMS layout in Eclipse. I believe you can also override the Application class to listen for a "Low Memory" warning function.

When you read in the Bitmap through the BitmapFactory, set the BitmapFactory.Option inScaled parameter to 2 or 4 (or whatever works for you) to create a smaller, less memory intensive image.

Generally, there is only one solution: use smaller images. If there's no code it's hard to say what's exactly wrong. You may try to lower image size.

Comment: I tried reducing the image size, the problem still remains. The log said it cannot allocate even 103 Kb.

04-30 16:58:21.833: E/dalvikvm-heap(3654): 105376-byte external allocation too large for this process.
04-30 16:58:21.841: E/(3654): VM won't let us allocate 105376 bytes

Comment: you can send me the images used in the layout and I'll try this on my end

Comment: My application uses database, and at the very first time it parse some XML data and insert into the Sqlite database. My out of memory problem occurs only at the first time. Second time it works fine. I tried System.gc(). Is there any prob on that. Or can I free memory on anyother way.

Comment: @Sniper for extracting thumbnail of image check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125779/how-to-compress-image-for-imageview-in-android/5337916#5337916

Answer (score 4):

in addition to what people have written here , i suggest watching this video of google , which point to some common memory issues and how to find the cause to your memory problem:

[Memory management for Android Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem before and I was debugging on S4 android 4.3.
The solution was : **Copy the images from the mdpi folder to hdpi folder (so they are now on both folder)**

I know weird! but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seams like ur image is big size so u can decode your image and use  **android:largeHeap="true".** inside manifest of Application Tag

Answer (score 0):

you might have gone through all the above solutions, but still give it a try.
I was lost in finding a solution until I got it work.
This might night work for your case (Excuse me in that case).

myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);                                                   myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

place these before you call your activity.

Comment: I don't think this is a `legit` answer