# Android: Error inflating class <unknown> caused by OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, imageview

I have a Error inflating class  error that seemed to be caused by Bitmap (more details here: [Android: Memory error because of an ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684165/android-memory-error-because-of-an-imageview)) but when I comment the bitmap I still have the error while when I comment the Imageview5, no error. All the posts on stackoverflow about this error did not help solving my problem

```
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kersplatt/com.example.kersplatt.ShareActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at com.example.kersplatt.ShareActivity.onCreate(ShareActivity.java:64)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    ... 11 more
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    ... 23 more
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    ... 26 more
```

and my line 23 is imageview5

```
   <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView5"
         android:layout_width="85dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:src="@drawable/diviseur" />
```

Comment: did u try loading a different image in the src? what is the size of the image u add?

Comment: did you compiled it completely after commenting out the bitmap?

Comment: Ok, thanks Ajay I changed the image and it worked. I have no idea why as my image "diviseur" was used in other activities and it did not lead to errors

Answer (score 5):

It's a pretty misleading error, but it's caused by a nested exception, because the VM has run out of memory for the drawable diviseur. See the end of the stack trace:

```
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:118)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
02-04 10:03:04.353: E/AndroidRuntime(17427):    ... 26 more
```

Comment: I don't think this is the error as I already used diviseur in the activity before this one, and had no error :/

Comment: Be sure to clean and rebuild the project. What are the dimensions of the drawable?

Comment: Cleaned and rebuilt did not help. Yet, I have tried with another picture, it worked. As I don't need a specific picture (I change it immediately while loading), I'm fine with that, even if it is quite strange. Have you an idea why I can't use this image because it was used in the precedent activity? Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this may happen, the best practice is to create a scaled bitmap using the bitmap factory,

```
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapPicture,
                    imageWidth, imageHeight, false);
```

Try this and see if it helps

Also use,

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to garbage collector that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
opts.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];
```

and always recycle your bitmap when you leave that activity as it helps in freeing memory.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. My problem was that every phone loaded a 2k image as background of the activity. I solved the problem by scaling down this background image to 800x480 and 1280x720. Then I put this images into the ldpi, mdpi, ... folders.Now it works